# Day part of Python Datetime keeps breaking

Tags: python, datetime

I have extracted a set of values from a CSV into a Pandas dataframe. One of these is a date and time value formatted as YY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS:MS

So something like: 23:09:28 16:03:40:7

I am attempting to convert it to a date value using datetime.date with the formatting "%y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S".

However, the %d part of it seems to be broken... it keeps turning blue and I get an error message saying 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

```
date = datetime.datetime(df['RunStartTime'][row], "%y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S").date
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. As for `YY:MM:DD` why do you assume this isn't a *time*? Where does this bad format come from? Even if you're absolutely sure 23 is a year you can't be sure it's not 1923. Before COVID-19, the big IT news was how LLoyd's and other banks crashed because their systems started translating `20` to `1920`

Comment: The data I'm working with presents it's date/time in the format I've listed. 

I know it's a date because that is the documentation I've been working with. What I am trying to figure out is how to convert it from the string value it's in into a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using a Pandas dataframe, you could try using [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to create a date column. Also, your example appears to have milliseconds but you're missing `:%f` at the end of your format string.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RunStartTime'], format="%y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S:%f").dt.normalize()
```